# How does the induced representation depend on the coset representatives?

Tags: representation-theory

Suppose that $\pi : H \rightarrow V$ is a linear representation of some finite group $H$ and let $H$ be a subgroup of $G$. Let me first outline the construction of the induced representation, partially following the Wikipedia article.

Let $g_1, \dots, g_{n}$ be a full set of representatives in $G$ of the left cosets in $G/H$. The induced representation $\operatorname{Ind}_H^G\pi$ can be thought of as acting on the following space:

$W=\bigoplus_{i=1}^n g_i V$

Here each $g_{i} V$ is an isomorphic copy of the vector space $V$ whose elements are written as $g_{i} v$ with $v \in V$.
For each $g \in G$ and each $g_{i}$ there is an $h_{i}(g)$ in $H$ and $j_i(g)$ in $\{1, ..., n\}$
such that $g g_{i} = g_{j_i(g)} h_{i}(g)$. 
Via the induced representation $G$ acts on $W$ as follows:

$g \cdot \sum_{i=1}^n g_i v_i = \sum_{i=1}^n g_{j_i(g)} \pi(h_i(g)) v_i$

where $v_i \in V$ for each $i$.

Let $g'_1, \dots, g'_{n}$ be another full set of representatives in $G$ of the left cosets in $G/H$.
This can be as trivial as a permutation of the first set of representatives
or more complicated. We can again construct the induced representation
by the recipe stated above. Let's call it $\operatorname{OtherInd}_H^G\pi$

**Question:**
How are these two induced representations related? I know they are equivalent but what is the structure of the equivalence transformation?

Most textbooks are content with stating that the construction does not depend on the set of representatives *up to equivalence* but I would like to understand what the isomorphism between $\operatorname{Ind}_H^G\pi$ and $\operatorname{OtherInd}_H^G\pi$ actually looks like.

Answer (score 1):

There is an equivalence $\phi$ between the two defined induced representations which is defined by the property that whenever $g_i=g_j'h$ (where $h\in H$) we have $\phi(g_iv)=g_j'\pi(h)v$.

Both versions are (to my mind, at least) simply giving a concrete basis to the tensor product

$$ \mathrm{Ind}_H^GV:=\mathbb{C}[G]\otimes_{\mathbb{C}[H]}V. $$

Because of the $\mathbb{C}[H]$-subscript, elements of $H$ may be slid across the tensor symbol willy-nilly, and therefore any element $g\otimes v$ may be turned into $g_i\otimes \pi(h)v$ for some $h\in H$. Thus, while $\{g\otimes v_j\}$ may be a spanning set if $\{v_j\}$ is a basis for $V$, it can be turned into a basis $\{g_i\otimes v_j\}$ with $\{g_i\}$ a transversal for $G/H$.